# Como saber quais métodos e propriedades eu coloco em uma classe?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software

Vou fazer meu primeiro sistema comercial usando C#. O sistema será usado para gerenciar os hóspedes e os quartos de um pequeno hotel, por enquanto é só isso que ele pediu. Obviamente estou feliz com isso, ao mesmo tempo que sei que vou precisar aprender várias coisas específicas para entregar o sistema.

No momento eu já me reuni com o cara do sistema e recolhi os requerimentos, que de fato não são muitos. Em seguida eu vou fazer a modelagem do banco e mostrar para ele, e me parece que essa parte vai ser tranquila. A única coisa que está me preocupando de fato é que não faço ideia do que fazer para me organizar em relação às classes, quais serão suas propriedades e métodos.

Sei que existe o UML, mas tenho um problema em usá-lo. Não sei UML, e como tenho 3 semanas para desenvolver o sistema, não acredito que vou conseguir aprender UML nesse curto período de tempo.

Dessa forma eu queria saber se existe uma maneira simples de conseguir obter só isso mesmo : quais classes vou usar, quais serão seus atributos e métodos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A UML é uma linguagem visual utilizada essencialmente para documentar e comunicar decisões de projeto realizadas utilizando a orientação a objetos. Você *não precisa* conhecer UML para construir seu software nesse paradigma, principalmente se vai trabalhar sozinho. Ainda assim, o dia que tiver um tempinho valeria a pena estudar os diagramas de Caso de Uso e de Classes. O primeiro é útil na comunicação com o cliente e no entendimento de seu problema e de suas expectativas. Já o segundo é útil justamente no escopo da sua pergunta: entender o que produzir em termos de classes, atributos e métodos.

Bom, na Orientação a Objetos e resolução computacional de um problema se dá por meio da troca de mensagens entre objetos instanciados a partir de classes. Cada classe tem responsabilidades bem definidas (ela *faz* algo) e para auxiliar nisso mantém estados internos por meio de atributos (ela *tem* algo). Considere, por exemplo no seu domínio de problema, uma classe `quarto` e uma classe `cliente`. A classe `quarto` tem atributos importantes relacionados à entidade do mundo real, tais como número do quarto, estado de ocupação (ocupado, vago), estado de limpeza (precisa de limpeza, quarto limpo), indicação sobre ter ou não TV, número de camas, etc. Além disso, ela tem métodos que permitem realizar as ações envolvendo os quartos, tais como reservar (para um determinado `cliente`), bloquear (impedir reservas, no caso de manutenção), solicitar limpeza (envolvendo uma outra potencial classe `camareira`), etc.

A escolha das classes, seus atributos e a relação entre elas (essa dependência a respeito do `quarto` poder ser reservado para um `cliente`, por exemplo) depende fortemente do seu *domínio de problema*. Isto é, depende do que precisa ser implementado para resolver o problema do seu cliente (nesse caso, o hotel). Independentemente de você utilizar ou não um Diagrama de Classes UML, você vai precisar primeiramente listar as entidades, concretas ou abstratas, que precisam ser representadas para que o seu sistema seja capaz de oferecer a solução que o seu cliente (o hotel) espera. Por exemplo, `cliente`, `quarto`, `camareira`, `estadia`, `reserva`, `mensagem` deixada na recepção, item `consumível` de frigobar, etc. Então, você vai precisar listar os atributos de cada uma dessas classes, isto é, quais os dados que elas precisarão armazenar e manipular em seus respectivos escopos. Por exemplo, `cliente` tem `nome`, `CPF`, etc; `estadia` tem `data de início`, `data de fim`, `quarto`, `cliente`, etc. Finalmente você vai precisar definir os métodos que cada classe deverá prover para uso público (que possa ser executado/chamado/invocado por outras classes) e privadamente (que serve apenas para uso próprio e interno). Esses métodos são reralmente "funções" que executam algo importante *no escopo da classe*. Por exemplo, o `quarto` pode ter o método `reservar`, que faz exatamente o que diz: reserva o quarto para uso por um `cliente`; a `camareira` pode ter o método `alocar`, que registra o `quarto` e o período do dia em que o(a) funcionário(a) precisa fazer a limpeza.

Uma dificuldade que você certamente terá é saber diferenciar o que é suficientemente importante para ser representado como uma classe ou deve ser apenas representado como um atributo de outra classe. Por exemplo, se no seu domínio de problema a TV precisa ser manipulada pelo seu sistema (porque o seu sistema deve controlar os canais liberados, já que isso depende do pacote que o cliente vai pagar), você certamente vai precisar ter uma classe `TV` que tenha atributos para os diferentes canais e métodos para liberá-los ou bloqueá-los (além é claro de ter que implementar a interface com a TV real mesmo diretamente no quarto!). Por outro lado, se o seu sistema não tem esse tipo de interface e a TV é meramente algo que pode ou não existir no quarto, basta tê-la como um atributo da classe `quarto` (um atributo booleano indicando se tem ou não uma TV, ou um atributo numérico que identifique o tipo de TV - 0 para TV simples, 1 para TV a cabo com poucos canais, 2 para TV a cabo com muitos canais, etc).

Por fim, note que o Diagrama de Classes (seja ou não representado/documentado em UML) *não é* exatamente a mesma coisa que o Modelo Entidade-Relacionamento (as tabelas do seu banco de dados). Naturalmente, o seu sistema precisará persistir (armzenar em tabelas) os dados que manipula, e a escolha de como isso será feito depende do que precisa ser representado no sistema (nas classes). Mas elas são representações distintas. Os objetos instanciados a partir de classes têm referências uns para os outros (o cliente está em um quarto, que são ambos referenciados pela reserva, por exemplo), enquanto que no seu banco de dados as tabelas usam códigos (em chaves primárias e estrangeiras) para fazer essa referenciação indiretamente. Tais códigos podem ou não ser interessantes para exibição para humanos. Por exemplo, o atendente do hotel provavelmente vai precisar referenciar o código do cliente e o número do quarto, mas a reserva pode ou não ter um código. Talvez o hotel esteja acostumado a "pensar" na reserva em termos apenas do cliente e do quarto. Isso não quer dizer que o seu sistema não precise utilizar um identificador interno para referenciar as reservas (em outras palavras, a tabela "reserva" no banco de dados deve ter uma chave primária).

Assim, eu sugeriria primeiramente trabalhar no modelo de domínio (nas classes, atributos e métodos) pra entender bem o que o seu sistema precisa representar e manipular, pra só então pensar a respeito de como essas entidades precisam ser persistidas/armazenadas.

Também sugiro que você leia bastante a respeito da Orientação a Objetos. Aqui mesmo no SOPT há a tag [orientação-a-objetos](/questions/tagged/orienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos) que tem muita coisa útil. E, eventualmente, se tiver dúvidas, poste novas perguntas de forma pontual (por exemplo: pensei em fazer a classe X com o atributo Y, mas não sei como representar isso, alguma dica?).

Comment: Excelente resposta. Ao longo do tempo vamos entendendo o verdadeiro valor da engenharia de software.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe um software para fazer a análise do sistema sozinho.

Como tal os metodos e as propriedades são definidas apartir das suas necessidades.

Modelando o sistema em UML teria a vantagem de saber em antemão quais seriam as suas necessidades completas.

Neste caso como o tempo é curto, têm de ir verificando quais serão consoante vai avançando no projeto.

Sets e Gets serão necessários, entre outras funções para poder gerir o seu modelo de negócio.

Aconselho a fazer uma breve modelagem em papel, com as funcionalidades que o sistema terá de abrenger e que metodos/propriedades ira precisar para completar essa funcionalidade com sucesso.